# Using pandas.Series.dtype as dict keys?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I would like to create a dictionary using pandas.Series.dtype as keys. However, this does not work. See this example.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np

switcher = {
    np.int64: "It's an int!",
    np.float64: "It's a float!"}

df = DataFrame({'x1': [1,2,3,4], 'x2': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]})

x1_dtype = df['x1'].dtype

print(switcher.get(np.int64))
# prints: It's an int!

print(switcher.get(np.int64, "Key not found!"))
# prints: It's an int!

print(switcher.get(x1_dtype, "Key not found!"))
# prints: Key not found!

print(x1_dtype == np.int64)
# prints: True
```

I don't understand the result of the last two print statements. Apparently x1_dtype == np.int64 is true, yet when I say switcher.get(x1_dtype) it does not find any suitable key. After some time I realized that the root cause is that hashes for the two different keys are not same:

```
# Following line is False
hash(np.int64) == hash(x1_dtype)
```

So, I cannot compare the two naively using switcher.get. Next idea was to stringify them, but that does not work neither:

```
print(str(np.int64))
# prints: <class 'numpy.int64'>

print(str(x1_dtype))
# prints: int64
```

Yet, the pandas docs state that string comparisons should work (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dtypes):

> For methods requiring dtype arguments, strings can be specified as indicated.

Looks like I misunderstand this statement. Any idea how such a thing can be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to my knowledge, your `x1_dtype` is an instance of `numpy.dtype`, whereas`np.int64` is an enum that the `numpy.dtype` class uses to construct a specific dtype.

Only `x1_dtype` is an instance of `numpy.dtype`:

```
>>> type(x1_dtype)
<class 'numpy.dtype'>

>>> type(np.int64)
<class 'type'>
```

Use `np.int64` to construct an actual dtype:

```
>>> np.int64
<class 'numpy.int64'>

>>> x1_dtype
dtype('int64')

>>> np.dtype(np.int64)
dtype('int64')
```

So `np.dtype` uses an underlying type (e.g. `np.int64`) to construct a data type object. Thankfully you can access the underlying type via `np.dtype(...).type` and use that to compare:

```
>>> x1_dtype.type
<class 'numpy.int64'>

# which is the same class as np.int64
>>> np.int64
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

So to get your code to work, we just need to use the underlying type of the dtype object.

```
>>> switcher.get(x1_dtype.type, "Key not found!")
"It's an int!"
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! It is indeed working in this way!

Comment: Actually I think `np.int64` is a function; that's what the `type` type is.  We can `np.int64(10)`.  That constructs an array with the right dtype.

Comment: `np.int64(...)` returns an instance of `np.int64`: `type(np.int64(10))` repr's `<class 'numpy.int64'>` This leads me to assume `np.int64` is indeed a class and not a function (also `type(np.int64)` repr's to `<class 'function'>`, not `<class 'type'>`. Though, regardless of the semantics, you are correct in that this behavior is not characteristic of an `enum` since enums aren't normally callable

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing a class (np.int64) with an instance of that class (x1_dtype). Try this:

```
str(x1_dtype.__class__) == np.int64
```